# Laravel - Imagick not installed

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, imagick, php-imagine

using Laravel and trying to work on image upload using Imagine.

The issue is that I get the error stating:

```
Imagine \ Exception \ RuntimeException

Imagick not installed
Open: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/laravelcms/vendor/imagine/imagine/lib/Imagine/Imagick/Imagine.php

{
/**
* @throws RuntimeException
*/
public function __construct()
{
if (!class_exists('Imagick')) {
throw new RuntimeException('Imagick not installed');
}
```

I followed this guide, and correctly created all the folders and files etc as stated:

http://creolab.hr/2013/07/image-manipulation-in-laravel-4-with-imagine/

I have also checked the the Imagick folder with all files etc is in the correct location.

Any help?

Thanks, Craig.

Comment: Is Imagick in your `phpinfo();`?

Comment: You didn't install imagemagick extension. Follow the instructions [here](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.setup.php).

Comment: I see, and its not in my phpinfo. Thought it was already part of laravel but now i see its more to with the installed version of php. Shall install it thanks

Answer (score 8):

After some research, I found that MAMP 3 comes with Imagick pre-installed but not enabled by default.

Simply edit the php.ini file and search for:

```
;extension=imagick.so
```

Remove the ';' before it.

Comment: It is enabled by default at least in MAMP 3.3.1 (Windows): `C:\MAMP\conf\php7.1.5\php.ini` `extension=php_imagick.dll`

Answer (score 1):

If you have in fact installed it and it is still not working, a web server restart should do the trick. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Also for all other: do not forget that `artisan` will probably use separate php.ini, so will need to include `extension=imagick.so` there as well.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause is that you don't have Imagick installed. It does not come enabled on MAMP natively, so that is not surprising. [There are instructions on how to add it to MAMP here](https://github.com/delphian/drupal-convert-file/wiki/Installing-ImageMagick-on-Mac-OSX-for-PHP-and-MAMP).

Comment: Thanks, just got my head around composer now looking at ghost etc haha. Shall be a long evening. Thanks.